# Command to paste over but copy selected text

Tags: macos, copy-paste, intellij-idea

I'm looking for a command that pastes over a selection but copies the selection to the clipboard after pasting.  I'm working on OSX, would like an OS wide solution but an IntelliJ Idea solution would be pretty helpful if it's not possible on OSX